# Can someone tell me where I've gone wrong?

Tags: mesh, uv, baking

this is my first ever time working on blender. I'm following a tutorial and I made a dog house for the sims 4, I'm at the stage where I need to start baking but I have loads of layers, I tried to join them all together but some of walls disappeared.

Can someone help please :) ?
Thanks.

You can download my blender file here >>  http://simfileshare.net/download/5UT56PXIYey45CwzcPdPJetv6Wh1eLqjHK71SCVqgpMJaAski5ohs665AMNMDEh3/

Comment: It would be easier to tell, what mistakes you've made, if you'd give a link to the tutorial you're following.

Comment: Please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for blend files.

Comment: @RayMairlot the file was too big (nearly 19MB) and, btw, on that link it's already gone... I have a copy

Answer (score 2):

Some walls are "disappearing" during joining meshes because you have set Backface Culling in 3D view shading options. This makes faces, which normals are not directed towards viewer, not visible. What you need to do is, after joining meshes, Tab into edit mode, choose Face select, select "invisible" faces (you will be able to see black dots in the middle of each, even "invisible" face), Click on Flip Direction in left Shading panel or go to Mesh>Faces>Flip normals or press CTRL+F and choose Flip normals.

Answer (score 0):

the @Mzidare answer points you to solve some issues, but I saw also other ones:

some side faces are not correctly positioned, at least, eg:

[image]

then some other object mesh is 2d, ie has no depth (Z dimension here), eg:

[image]

this could or not be a problem importing or using this in "sims 4" but just for you to know this, even joined, will not be a "properly modelled" 3d object, imho, and issues like those could give you issues with some blender tool, if it expects a connected, proper (manifold) object to execute some operation... (eg: booleans)

I suggest, try to import what you have, then if it doesn't work well, come back here with another question to solve those issues. Let's hope it works well, though.